# Magento2: Tier price higher than regular price

Tags: magento2, price, overrides, tierprice, special-price

I figured out that if you set a tier price higher than the regular price, it will show the regular price anyway. Seems this is the "normal" funcionality, always show the lower price if it's possible.

But I need to change this funcionality, for example set a regular price of $10 for a product and $15 for a customer group X.

How can I do it? I don't know what to modify, I looked for `getFinalPrice` functions, but I don't see clearly where it does this logic of get the lower price.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem

You can look in this file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

Go to above file and start debugging as your issue related to tier price

you can look below methods for this issue

> - getBasePrice()
> - _applyTierPrice()
> - calculatePrice()

I think you need to modify all three methods.

Comment: @slayerbleast You are always welcome :)

Comment: is it possible to set negotiated price is greater than original price ?

Comment: @PratikMehta It will apply for all user, not for particular

Comment: Yes, But i can not do this i actually  stuck on $quote->collectTotals(); code.
Could you please help me ?